# Copy of ODT file on another computer doesn't contain formulas

Tags: worksheet-function, copy

Windows 10.  LibreOffice 7.0.3.1 (x64).  I copied an ODT file containing formulas to an external hard drive, connected the external drive to a different computer, copied the ODT file to the second computer.  The file loads into LO, but shows error messages - all the formulas are missing.  In the boxes where the formula would be, the boxes are empty.  When I made the ODT file on the first computer, I inserted the formulas into the doc using: new Par. > fn F3 and inserted the OLE object into the box.  On the first computer, the formulas are on the same hard drive but in a different sub-directory.  Even if I copy the Formulas sub-directory onto the second computer the path will be different.  Is there a way, on the second computer, to re-direct where LO will look for the formulas (ODF files) to insert into the document?

Answer (score 0):

If, as you stated, you created an OLE object on the first computer,
then it points to the first computer and will not work on another one.

LibreOffice has its own
[Math formula editor](https://elearn.ellak.gr/mod/page/view.php?id=2638).
As it uses a markup language to represent formulas (like HTML), the formulas will be
included in the document itself and be portable.

Comment: That was my thought, that the formula would be included in the document and be portable, but that's not what happened.  Is there another way to get the formula into the document in the first place that would make it portable?

Comment: Are you using the Math formula editor to create the formulas?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the markup language in the math editor to create the formula.

Comment: Did you use *Insert > Object > Formula* on the menu bar or *Insert > Object > OLE Object* (although I'm unsure if this would help)? In any case, I found that LO has many bugs with formulas disappearing ([example](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99225)) and none of them were ever solved.

Comment: HarryMC.  Thanks.  Yes, I tried both.  Didn't make any difference.  I haven't tried it yet but I think the answer may be to copy the Formulas folder and all the formulas (odf files) into the same directory the docs are in & copy the whole thing over.  Not the most elegant solution, but ...

Comment: The LO implementation of formulas as OLE objects is lousy. For portability, it might be best to replace them by images, or even use some other text editor.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies.  I got it working.  In the doc I open the formula editor using File > New > Formula.  Constructing the formula using the markup language in the formula editor, the result appears in the doc at the cursor position.  The formula is not saved.  To use the formula again use copy and paste.  Constructing an OLE object is the wrong way to do it.